# How to synchronization get mono object in nonblockthread?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor

1. Summarize the problem

I want to use orika to map the java bean and I create a orika filter the code is

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class OrikaMapperConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Bean
    public MapperFactory init(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
        mapperFactory.registerFilter(new CustomFilter<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            public boolean filtersSource() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean filtersDestination() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public <S, D> boolean shouldMap(Type<S> sourceType, String sourceName, S source, Type<D> destType, String destName, D dest, MappingContext mappingContext) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public <D> D filterDestination(D destinationValue, Type<?> sourceType, String sourceName, Type<D> destType, String destName, MappingContext mappingContext) {
                //how to get login User here with springfluxsecurity?
                //I want to modify the destinationValue dynamic with login user role
                return destinationValue;
            }

            @Override
            public <S> S filterSource(S sourceValue, Type<S> sourceType, String sourceName, Type<?> destType, String destName, MappingContext mappingContext) {
                return sourceValue;
            }
        });
        Map<String, IMapper> mappers = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(IMapper.class);
        mappers.forEach((key, iMapper) -> iMapper.register(mapperFactory));
        return mapperFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperFacade mapperFacade(MapperFactory mapperFactory) {
        return mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        init(applicationContext);
    }

}
```

2. Describe what you've tried

in method of `filterDestination` I try to use

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().map(context -> (User) context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).block()
```

to get login user but I get the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-tcp-nio-4
```

**Question:**
I want to know how to fix it ,thanks for your reply.

Comment: the error is quite clear dont use `block`, show us your entire filter destination, and explain what it is you actually want to do, why do you need the value.

Answer (score 1):

`.block()` calls were deprecated some time ago. As far as your `.map` method needs to work with the `User` itself and not with `Mono<User>`, the operator you should apply instead is `.flatMap`. This will unwrap your user from the Mono and will be trigger when the User "promise" is resolved.